# 301 Redirect subpages to new main page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi I am new to redirects.

I can get the basic Redirect 301 /page1/ https://example.com/newpage/ redirects to work fine.

I am having an issue with removing a parent page and all of it's child pages and redirecting everything to a new parent page.

The main redirect works:

```
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/ htps://example.com/procedures-services/
```

But trying to redirect the sub pages

```
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/hearing-services/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
```

Is redirecting to /procedures-services/hearing-services/ which doesn't exist.

Here is what the .htaccess file looks like, the 2-7 do not redirect properly:

```
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/hearing-services/ https://example.com/procedures-services
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/hearing-aids/ https://example.com/procedures-services
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/self-test-your-hearing/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/schedule-your-hearing-evaluation/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/financing/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/dual-sensory-wellness/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /about-costello-eye-physicians/community-involvement/ https://example.com/about-costello-eye-physicians/in-the-news/
```

There are some more redirect's but I can only post 7 links. Further down the .htaccess file after some iThemes security stuff is this:

```
# Stop wordpress username enumeration vulnerability
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?author=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/? [L,R=301]
```

and also this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I doubt that your redirections really work the way you posted them. Please note that your rewriting target `example.com/procedures-services/` points to a _relative_ URL, so a _folder_ inside the host you are trying to redirect away from. What you probably meant was: `https://example.com/procedures-services/`.

Comment: Your actual issue here most likely is the order of rules. You need to specify the more detailed rules first, so further up in the file. So _first_ the exceptions, _then_ the more general rules.

Comment: @arkascha you are correct the .htaccess file does list the URL as https://example.com I mistakenly left that off. Fixed in the original post. The first line in the .htaccess file is the second "code" section listed in the original post.

There are 14 redirects and the only 6 that don't work are the subpages of /eye-can-hear/

Comment: Please modify the question and post the exact configuration file you currently have. Things are getting confusing here.

Comment: I have modified the question

Comment: I already told you in my second comment that you need to change the order of rewriting rules. You place the general rule before the exceptions. That won't work. Did you even bother to read my comment?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if I put the redirects after that other stuff. The subpages still come back 404 and do not redirect

Comment: The order inside the block of redirects...

Comment: I give up. I change the order around and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this lines (2-7) that do not redirect properly to this rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^eye-can-hear\/(.*)$ https://example.com/procedures-services [R=301,L]
```

It's redirect all subpages of /eye-can-hear/* to https://example.com/procedures-services

Answer (score 0):

This line of code worked for me in the .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /eye-can-hear/(.*) https://example.com/procedures-services
```

It redirects the page https://example.com/eye-can-hear/ and its subpages to the URL https://example.com/procedures-services

Answer (score 0):

(Answer after two years, but maybe it helps someone)

In the htaccess file, you should put this redirection after all other redirections of subpages:

```
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
```

Your htaccess should be like this:

```
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/hearing-services/ https://example.com/procedures-services
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/hearing-aids/ https://example.com/procedures-services
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/self-test-your-hearing/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/schedule-your-hearing-evaluation/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/financing/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/dual-sensory-wellness/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
Redirect 301 /eye-can-hear/ https://example.com/procedures-services/
```